# finding very small values of $r + s\sqrt p + t\sqrt q$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

For integers $p$, $q$ I'm interested in finding good approximations to $0$ of the form $r + s\sqrt p + t\sqrt q$ for rational $r$, $s$ and $t$.

In particular, I'd like to generate approximations where $r$, $s$ and $t$ are moderately sized but for which the sign of $r + s\sqrt p + t\sqrt q$ cannot be resolved correctly using double precision arithmetic.

I'd also be interested in specific examples, e.g. for $p = 2$, $q = 3$.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that there is a single "best method" for generating such approximations.  Are you familiar with continued fractions?  They might help your search.

Comment: I've added the [tag:number-theory] tag because I think people familiar with number theory would be able to say something about this problem.  If anyone can think of a more appropriate tag then please replace it!

Comment: @user5402 do you have an example?

Comment: I think that Shidlovski'i bound will give you a lower bound on how large $r,s,t$ need to be to get this as close to zero as needed (it is a lower bound to the approximation error of algebraic numbers by rational linear combination of other algebraic numbers). Can't say more at this time. Need to go take a look at missus' bike - it is making funny noises.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means for a rational number to be "moderateley sized". Consider all the expressions $a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3$ with $a,b,c$ all of the form $p/q$ with $0\le p\le q\le100$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$. There are about $30,000,000,000$ such numbers, they are all different, and they are all less than $4.2$, so there are two whose difference, which is also of the form $r+s\sqrt2+t\sqrt3$, is less than $1.4\times10^{-10}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson An example: -7/80+99/64*sqrt(2)-97/80*sqrt(3)<1.19E-10.  Not sure yet if there are any others...